# Android : ImageVIew onTouch Drag is intercepted by ScrollView ontouch Event

Tags: android, android-imageview, ontouchlistener, android-scrollview

I was working with a imageview controller inside a scrollview. When it comes to implementation and testing, I have found that the scrolling always override the onTouch event than the imageView (dragImage) .

I try to use this to enable the scrolling

```
scv.setOnTouchListener(null);
```

And this to disable

```
scv.setOnTouchListener( new OnTouchListener(){ 
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return true; 
    }
});
```

It shows hat the dragImage drags only a very little movement instead of draging where I want freely . Would you please tell me the better way to disable scrolling when I touch the ImageView instead of scrollView ?

The below is my working:

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment   {



private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section number.
     */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);            
        return fragment;
    }




    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View  rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_flight_bank, container, false);
        r1  = (RelativeLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayouyt1);

        r2  = (RelativeLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayouyt2);
        r3  = (RelativeLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayouyt3);
        r4  = (RelativeLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayouyt4);
        r5  = (RelativeLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayouyt5);
        rTop  = (RelativeLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rTop);

        scv = (ScrollView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.scrollView1);
        initialise(rootView);

        return rootView;
    }



    private void initialise(View rootView) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        tvCustom= (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.ttvCustomize);
        tvRename= (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvRename);
        tvNormal= (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvNorma);
        tvExper= (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txExper);


    ...
            dragImage = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.dragImage);
            //dragImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        dragImage.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
            private int _xDelta;
            private int _yDelta;
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                final int X = (int) event.getRawX();
                final int Y = (int) event.getRawY();
                switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lParams =      (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) dragImage
                    .getLayoutParams();

                    _xDelta = X - lParams.leftMargin;
                    _yDelta = Y - lParams.topMargin;
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams ParamsA = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) dragImage
                    .getLayoutParams();
                    ParamsA.leftMargin = X - _xDelta;
                    ParamsA.topMargin = Y - _yDelta;
                    ParamsA.rightMargin = -250;
                    ParamsA.bottomMargin = -250;

                    dragImage.setLayoutParams(ParamsA);
                    break;
                }
                return true;

            }

        });
```

Solution: 
Insert at the beginnging (onCreteView)

```
scv.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() 
        {
            public boolean onTouch(View p_v, MotionEvent p_event) 
            {
                dragImage.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                //  We will have to follow above for all scrollable contents
                return false;
            }
        });
```

In setOnTouchListener, onTouch method:

```
v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
```

Comment: Could you give an example of what you are trying to do? Do you have a list with `ImageViews` and you are trying to drag in image from a row?

Answer (score 7):

Add the following code to your `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` and `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` case should solve your problem:

```
dragImage.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
```

Comment: Thanx it wokred for me

Answer (score 0):

I was finally to get this working, you also need to return true in the onTouch event. The following code will scale your image to fill the imageview pixel width. User can drag cover pic to reposition, you will need to track Y matrix for later display.  ImageView scale type is set to Matrix.

```
//declare in activity
private float lastY = 0;

//Added to onCreate of Activity
            if (CoverPic!=null){
            CoverPic.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                     if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                         lastY = event.getY();
                         CoverPic.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                         return true;
                     } 
                     else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                         float[] values = new float[9];
                         Matrix m = CoverPic.getImageMatrix();
                         m.getValues(values);
                         float y = values[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];
                         float deltaY = lastY - event.getY();                            
                         y -= deltaY;

                         //original height / original width x new width = new height
                         int newwidth = CoverPic.getWidth();
                         float curwidth = CoverPic.getMeasuredWidth();
                         curwidth = CoverPic.getDrawable().getBounds().width();
                         float newscale = newwidth / curwidth;

                         //We need to limit y Max and Min
                         int viewheight = CoverPic.getHeight();
                         float curheight = CoverPic.getDrawable().getBounds().height() * newscale;
                         float limitmove = curheight - viewheight;
                         limitmove = limitmove * -1;
                         if (y<limitmove) y = limitmove;
                         if (y>0) y = 0;                             

                         Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                         matrix.postScale(newscale, newscale);
                         matrix.postTranslate(values[Matrix.MTRANS_X], y);

                         profile.setCoverOffY(y); //Update profile cover for saving                          
                         CoverPic.setImageMatrix(matrix);                            
                         CoverPic.invalidate();
                         CoverPic.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                         return true;
                     } 
                     else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                         CoverPic.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                         return true;
                     }
                     return false;
                }
            }
            );                          
        }
```